# how to use querySelectorAll on the added nodes in a MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, selectors-api

I'm trying to create a `querySelectorAll` function in a `MutationObserver`, so it's like calling `querySelectorAll` to the newly added elements. The reason for this is so it works with other existing code.

This is proving to be hard without hard-coding selectors and using `if` statements, I've thought of the following ways which all failed:

- Try to use the added node's parent's `querySelectorAll`, but then it includes elements that are not just added.
- Use the added node `querySelectorAll` function and merge all the results, but it doesn't work as doesn't include the added node itself.
- Create a new element and move all the added nodes to it, and call `querySelectorAll` on that element, but then the nodes disappear after the `MutationObserver` runs and don't get added.

Is there a way to do this, or some modification to one of the ways I've come up with so it works?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll try but it's a bit hard since this is a Google browser extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, your callback receives an array of [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord)s, each of which has a `NodeList` of added nodes called `addedNodes`.

Turning those into a list of elements matching a selector is probably more complicated than it ideally would be, but here's one approach (see comments):

```
function applySelector(selector, records) {
    // We can't create a NodeList; let's use a Set
    const result = new Set();
    // Loop through the records...
    for (const {addedNodes} of records) {
        for (const node of addedNodes) {
            // If it's an element...
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                // Add it if it's a match
                if (node.matches(selector)) {
                    result.add(node);
                }
                // Add any children
                addAll(result, node.querySelectorAll(selector));
            }
        }
    }
    return [...result]; // Result is an array, or just return the set
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const ob = new MutationObserver(records => {
    const result = applySelector("span", records);
    console.log(`Got ${result.length} matches:`);
    for (const span of result) {
        console.log(span.id);
    }
});
const target = document.getElementById("target");
ob.observe(target, {childList: true});
target.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    `<div>
      blah
      <span id="span1">span</span>
      blah
      <div>
        <span id="span2">lorem <span id="span3">ipsum</span></span>
      </div>
    </div>`
);

function addAll(set, list) {
    for (const entry of list) {
        set.add(entry);
    }
}
function applySelector(selector, records) {
    // We can't create a NodeList; let's use a Set
    const result = new Set();
    // Loop through the records...
    for (const {addedNodes} of records) {
        for (const node of addedNodes) {
            // If it's an element...
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                // Add it if it's a match
                if (node.matches(selector)) {
                    result.add(node);
                }
                // Add any children
                addAll(result, node.querySelectorAll(selector));
            }
        }
    }
    return [...result]; // Result is an array, or just return the set
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm thanks I guess that's a bit more complicated than I thought but it works. Thanks for telling me about the `.matches` function, this avoids hard-coding at least.

Comment: @simonzack - Yeah, `matches` is great. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `addedNodes` is a NodeList collection. You can achieve something nearly identical to `querySelectorAll` by calling `Array.prototype.filter` on it, where the callback checks whether the given element `.matches` the selector passed:

```js
new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  const { addedNodes } = mutationsList[0];
  const matches = [...addedNodes]
    .filter(node => node.nodeType === 1)
    .filter(element => element.matches('.someDiv'));
  if (matches.length) {
    console.log(matches);
  }
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    `<div class="someDiv">dynamically added matching</div>
     <div class="nonMatching">dynamically added non-matching</div>`
  );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="somediv">existing</div>
```

Just replace the selector string passed to `.matches` with whatever selector string you want to filter by.

If you want to check whether *any* child elements of the `addedNodes` match the selector, and not just the `addedNodes` themselves, you can use something like `flatMap` to extract the array of sub-matches from each element, if you want:

```js
new MutationObserver((mutationsList) => {
  const { addedNodes } = mutationsList[0];
  const elements = [...addedNodes]
    .filter(node => node.nodeType === 1);
  const matches = [
    ...elements.filter(element => element.matches('.someDiv')),
    ...elements.flatMap(element => [...element.querySelectorAll('.someDiv')])
  ];
  if (matches.length) {
    console.log(matches);
  }
})
  .observe(document.body, { childList: true });
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    `<div class="someDiv">dynamically added matching
       <div class="someDiv">dynamically added matching nested</div>
    </div>
     <div class="nonMatching">dynamically added non-matching</div>`
  );
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="somediv">existing</div>
```

Comment: What about descendant elements of the added elements that match? :-)

Comment: Hm maybe I haven't explained myself clearly, but the goal is to have a function which proxies `querySelectorAll`, I did already try using `filter`, the current hard-coded solution uses a generator.

Comment: @simonzack `querySelectorAll` runs only on a Document or on an element - it doesn't run on a NodeList, so you can't use it directly - something like `.filter` and `.matches` is the best alternative.

Comment: @simonzack - The trick is since the observer's callback gets an array of records, which then have NodeLists of added nodes, you'd basically have to add `querySelectorAll` to `Array.prototype`, which probably wouldn't be ideal. :-)